# Add Scala as Code Language for [chisel] tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

Chisel is a DSL embedded in Scala. It would be beneficial if code blocks in questions tagged [chisel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chisel) were syntax highlighted as Scala by default. Is there a way I can edit the tag or is this something mods have to do?

Comment: It's possible, a [few anointed people](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting) can push the buttons that associates the tag.  Looks entirely appropriate to me.  Hopefully they see your post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It’s something only mods can do.

I’ve set the tag to default to Scala when picking a language to highlight code blocks:

[image: screenshot of a section of the Chisel tag wiki page with a drop-down selector, set to <code>lang-scala</code>, circled in red with a hand-drawn line]